# Using expression to change box color

Tags: sql, reporting-services

I have 2 columns that have data.  Column 1 i want to turn green if over 25% and column 2 i want to turn green if over 10.  If column 2 is green i dont want it to change color in column 1 and vice versa.

This is column 1

```
=IIF(Fields!New_Strategic_Devices_Qty.Value / Fields!New_and_Upgrade_Postpaid_phones.Value > 0.2199 , "SpringGreen" , IIF(Fields!New_Strategic_Devices_Qty.Value / Fields!New_and_Upgrade_Postpaid_phones.Value < 0.2199 , "White" , 0))
```

Below is what i have currently for COlumn 2.

```
=IIF(Fields!New_Strategic_Devices_Qty.Value>=ReportItems!newstratgoal.Value,"LimeGreen", iif(ReportItems!pull_through_percent.Value >0.2199,"White","DimGray"))
```

Comment: you need to provide some more details to get answered your query. Provide some sample data and what you have tried.

Comment: I have tried the above with and/or statements... The result is hard to show here.  Basically if condition 1 is met then condition 2 does nothing. I have set color formatting only to change

Comment: So what happens when both conditions are met (C1 > 25% and C2 > 10)?  Ignore the **Sample Data** and **Show Your Work** guys. They ask for more detail and then rarely help - they ask for more info because they don't know the product.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds to me that you need to write the same formula twice, which is bad practice regarding readability and maintenance.  I have a solution for you to optimize this design you are working on.

You will want to use a Variable on the Group Properties and set the expression there.  Once you've done that you can reference these variables as an expression in the report body with syntax: `=Variables!myVariableName.Value`.  Once you have defined the group variables it should be much simpler to achieve the logic you are working to define.  You can reference the group variable in both the `[Field Expression]` and the `[Color Expression]`.

I would also recommend using SWITCH instead of IIF, switch is more readable and is simpler to define more rules in the expression.  Here are some examples using switch.  Please not that the ELSE condition in the last expression requires 'true' to evaluate implicit conditions.

I hope this helps with your solution.

**Two reference articles**:

- https://www.sqlchick.com/entries/2010/11/24/deciding-whether-to-use-an-expression-or-a-variable-in-ssrs.html
- [MS DOCS: Built-in Collections - Report and Group Variables References](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/reporting-services/report-design/built-in-collections-report-and-group-variables-references-report-builder?view=sql-server-2017)

**Group Variable, Expression Demo**:

```
[fxSal_PositiveResult]:
=SWITCH(
    (
        Fields!SAL27.Value= 0
        OR  (Fields!SAL27.Value= 1 AND Fields!SAL28.Value= -1)
        OR  (Fields!SAL27.Value= -2 AND Fields!SAL28.Value<> 1)
    ), Fields!SAL27.Value
    ,true, Fields!SAL28.Value
)

[fxCampy_PositiveResult]:
=SWITCH(
    (
        Not(IsNothing(Fields!CAM11.Value))
    ), Fields!CAM11.Value
    ,true, Fields!CAM12.Value
)
```

**Demo, Screenshot**:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure how you expect to deal with colors when both conditions are met - Column1 > 25% and Column2 > 10. I'll **ass**u**me** that Column 1 has precedence in this case.

For the first Column's **BackgroundColor** property, you would have

```
=IIF(Fields!New_Strategic_Devices_Qty.Value / Fields!New_and_Upgrade_Postpaid_phones.Value > 0.25, 
    "SpringGreen", 
    "White")
```

For the second column you do need the extra IIF from column 1's color to check the first column's color,

```
=IIF(Fields!New_Strategic_Devices_Qty.Value >= ReportItems!newstratgoal.Value, 
    IIF(Fields!New_Strategic_Devices_Qty.Value / Fields!New_and_Upgrade_Postpaid_phones.Value > 0.25, 
        "LimeGreen",
        "White"))
```

Incidentally, for the expression you gave, you don't need the second IIF, it would be covered by the ELSE of the first IIF unless the value is EXACLTY 21.99%. A color of 0 would probably give an error anyways.

```
=IIF(Fields!New_Strategic_Devices_Qty.Value / Fields!New_and_Upgrade_Postpaid_phones.Value > 0.2199 , 
    "SpringGreen" , 
    IIF(Fields!New_Strategic_Devices_Qty.Value / Fields!New_and_Upgrade_Postpaid_phones.Value < 0.2199 , "White" , 0))
```

I prefer **MintCream** for highlighting in green.

Comment: Well to answer your first question.  I would like it to see if first condition is met and do nothing... and vice versa. So if column 1 cond. is met then column 2 will remain white even if over 10. and then vice versa for the same.